# problem compiling ros with standalone opencv 2.3.1

Tags: ros, pi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi:

I having trouble getting rosmake to compile with the new version of opencv. I keep getting "fatal error: opencv-2.3.1/opencv2/features2d/features2d.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated."

I don't remember personally installing opencv, it must have come up with something else, perhaps (ROS-Electric). But anyway, I have the *.so.2.3.1 libraries in the /usr/lib folder and the include directory in /usr/include/opencv-2.3.1/opencv2/.... I set the C_PATH_INCLUDE and CPLUS_PATH_INCLUDE variables to the 2.3.1 directory and yet it still can't find the .h files.

What else is required so my package can see it? I think Cmakelists.txt only has the Find_Package(OpenCv) which only finds the old opencv and not the 2.3.1 version. I need it to be this version so I can use the simple blob detection api. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12196/problem-compiling-ros-with-standalone-opencv-2.3.1/) by [asrinivasan31](https://answers.ros.org/users/1262/asrinivasan31/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2011-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be helpful if you gave more information ... operating system, version of ROS, etc.

OpenCV is an external library in Electric (which I am guessing you are using). Try installing the library. On the Mac using homebrew do: brew install opencv.

In my CMakeLists.txt file to build a fictional program called test, I have the following:

```
find_package(OpenCV 2.3.1 REQUIRED)
rosbuild_add_executable(test src/test.cpp )
target_link_libraries(test ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

If you are not sure which opencv cmake is finding, you can do something like this to the CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(OpenCV_FOUND)
     message("====== Found ${OpenCV_VERSION} =======")
endif(OpenCV_FOUND)
```

Hope that helps!

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2011-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1